# How to make the page scroll to top when clicking different tabs in jquery vertical tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, scroll

I am a beginner in web designing.I used the Jquery vertical tab (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical)codes to create 6 tabs in my website. But when the tabs are clicked it doesn't scroll to top of the page. Thus, making it hard for people to read the description and the contents of each tab. They have to scroll all the way to the top.

these are the default codes I am using.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    });
</script>
```

Can someone please tell me how to add a code to make the webpage scroll back to the top when each tabs are clicked. I will really appreciate your help. Thanx

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp). `The scrollTo(x, y) method scrolls the content to the specified coordinates.`

`scrollTo(0,0)` should work perfectly for your purpose.

```
$( "#tabs li" ).click(function() {
   //user clicked on the li
   scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

If you need to scroll to the start of an element, first you need to calculate the offset of that element relative to the document. For that we can use the [.offset() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp).

```
$("#tabs li").click( function(){
    var tabs_offset = $("#tabs").offset();
    scrollTo(tabs_offset.left, tabs_offset.top);
});
```

Comment: Thanx Aneesh. Its going all the way to the page top. Is there a way to make it go to the div top? the tabs are inside the div called "tabs" <div id="tabs">. Anyway to scroll to the top of that? not all the way to the top of page

Comment: I changed the values for (x,y). Now its perfect. Thanx Aneesh :)

Comment: @user2195739 I just added how to dynamically calculate the offset of an element relative to the document. You shouldn't hardcode the x, y [unless you want to scroll to the top] as that would yield different positions in text in different window sizes.